# New installation of TFS: TFS Administration Console shows NO options - only Logs

Tags: windows, team-foundation-server

New installation of TFS: TFS Administration Console shows NO options - only Logs. I also do not have the "Team Foundation Server Administrators" user group that I believe should be added when TFS is installed. I am installing TFS on my local dev machine to play with setup options. Here are the relevant details:

- Host is Windows XP service pack 3 (x86)
- I am an administrator on the machine
- I am installing Team Foundation Server 2010 (x86)

Any ideas on how I can successfully install and configure TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that the information that I found that led me to believe that I could install TFS on windows XP is just wrong, or based on a beta version.

**TFS will only install on Windows Vista or higher (and of course, older server products)**